# How to reset the selection mark after you've changed the selection in a TListView?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-2009

I have a `TListView` in virtual mode and when I drag and drop an item I want to move the selection to the new item position. I do it clearing the selection and then set Selected of the desired item. It's ok, but there is a problem. After this happens if I hold shift and click a item (like multi selection) the list behaves like the start of the selection is the item that was selected before and not the one that I selected (with Selected:= True).

I tried to simulate a click, but after I move the mouse I get an access violation:

```
procedure TForm1.ListDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
 List.Perform(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, $002E001E);
 Sleep(10);
 List.Perform(WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, $002E001E);
end;
```

Comment: Pretty sure sending these messages and sleeping isn't the way to go. Surely this is possible without attempts to fake input. What did your original code look like. Any chance of a [mcve] for us to experiment with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After selecting the new item, you should set it as focused as well. But, more importantly, you need to send the ListView a [`LVM_SETSELECTIONMARK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/lvm-setselectionmark) message:

> The selection mark is the item index from which a multiple selection starts.

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.ListDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  ...
  Item := ...; // the list item after it has been moved to its new position...
  Item.Selected := True;
  Item.Focused := True;
  List.Perform(LVM_SETSELECTIONMARK, 0, Item.Index);
  List.Invalidate;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: That `LVM_SETSELECTIONMARK` is what was missing ! Thanks.